# Angular 2 / 4 - Redux - Design Choice - How many is too many observable subscriptions?

Tags: angular, performance, redux, ngrx

We are currently developing an Angular 4 app using redux (ngrx) to manage the state. One early design decision we made was to use smart components as a default and only use dumb components if they were reusable or likely to be reusable in the future.

Part of the app has a container component that contains a list of up to 100 records (components). Each record component has 2 subscriptions to data in the redux store which are rendered in the HTML template. This means we have 200 observable subscriptions active on the page.

My gut feeling says this is a performance code smell but I have no data to back this up. I don't yet have a feeling for the impact on resources a subscription to an observable has compared to just reading from a javascript object.

So I just wanted to see if people agree this a performance code smell ?

Note: I know we can change to pass in the list of records as one observable to the container component and pass the data to each record in the list using @Input

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes, I know it is hard to say for sure as it does depend on many factors (e.g. browser, server resources, code etc..). I was just hoping other users of angular and redux had faced this same design choice and could reveal some insight into their feelings on the subject.

FYI: In this case, providing you use observables in the html template, Angular manages the unsubscribe for you.

Comment: I think the record component should be dumbt component and should not subscribe to anything in store. Everything should be passed or getting from them through Input Output.

Comment: I agree with my predecessors. You can think of the state as a database. So a trigger of change would always be a subscription to a list. Everything else should be rendered in a dumb way.